# Subscribe to another publication after one has already loaded | React-Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, subscriptions

So I have 2 publications, **teams.dashboard** and **boards.board**, the thing is that, once the Boards fields have already loaded from **teams.dashboard** publication I want to load **boards.board** publication with the **boardId** from the first Board I have, for example: Boards.find().fetch()[0]._id.

Is there any React callback or Meteor way to subscribe to that once the props are ready? Because for some reason I'm subscribing to the data in the **componentDidUpdate** with a couple of 'ifs' and the websocket returns:

```
[{\"msg\":\"sub\",\"id\":\"R74JgCvWX8B8uphoZ\",\"name\":\"boards.board\",\"params\":[\"F4MuZ2jX8YKcf8fMr\"]}"]
```

but the next message is:

```
["{\"msg\":\"unsub\",\"id\":\"R74JgCvWX8B8uphoZ\"}"]
```

For some reason, the publication automatically unsubscribes...
Subsequently, there are two websocket messages which say the following

```
[{\"msg\":\"changed\",\"collection\":\"Boards\",\"id\":\"F4MuZ2jX8YKcf8fMr\",\"fields\":{\"field1\":false,\"field2\":[],\"field3\":false,\"field4\":[],\"field5\":[]}}"]
[{\"msg\":\"changed\",\"collection\":\"Boards\",\"id\":\"F4MuZ2jX8YKcf8fMr\",\"cleared\":[\"field1\",\"field2\",\"field3\",\"field4\",\"field5\"]}"]
```

Comment: You may find the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package useful for such joins. This would allow you to publish the related documents from both collections in a single publication.

Comment: I'm using publishComposite, what I want to do is, when i click a button, subscribe to boards.board which is a different publication, this already works. The problem is I want to subscribe automatically from the createContainer and set this.board.state but it seems to be impossible...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback parameter of `Meteor.subscribe` method to create another subscription.

```
Meteor.subscribe('teams.dashboard', () => {
    let firstBoard = Boards.findOne({}, {fields: {}});
    if (!firstBoard) {
        return;
    }

    Meteor.subscribe('boards.board', firstBoard._id);
}
```

of course, you have to manage your subscriptions. I'm not familiar if you can automatically unsubscribe in React components like Blaze can.

Comment: Is there any chance I can save the subscription on a state from the createContainer ?

Comment: Because now, what I have is a method that is boardSubscription that subscribes to the boardId you pass to the function and removes the actual subscriptions to not have data we don't need for the moment... The thing you are telling me now is to do everything on the createContainer and it's pretty impossible when changing the boardId

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It sounds specific to your application/React and not a general meteor question.

Comment: I could fix it by adding a ReactiveVar to the React Class, instead of using state or props since i couldnt access them from the createContainer